# Querydsl compare tuples

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

I'm trying to build a Querydsl expression in Java. I'm trying to get to:

`where (last_name, first_name, actor_id) < ('Allen', 'Meryl', 194)`

Where we're doing the tuple comparison. This is supported by mysql and postgres.

I've got all my ComparablePaths in:

```
List<ComparablePath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can assume this list is correctly populated (it is). So, I'm trying to do:

```
BooleanBuilder pred = new BooleanBuilder(Expressions.list(paths.toArray(new ComparablePath[0])).???);
```

But ??? does not have the `lt` operator. Just `eq`, `ne`, `in`, `not in`, etc. None of the comparison ones.

How can we generate the tuple comparison in querydsl?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the paths list is ordered the same way as the fields in the tuple we can do :

```
var pred = new BooleanBuilder();
pred.and(paths.get(0).lt("Allen"))
.and(paths.get(1).lt("Meryl"))
.and(paths.get(2).lt(194));
```

Comment: that's not what a tuple comparison does.  for instance `('a','c') < ('b','a')` is true, even though `'c' < 'a'` is false.  you'd need to build out `field1 < value1 or field1 = value1 and (field2 < value2 or field2 = value2 and field3 < value3)`

Comment: As @ysth pointed out, your answer is not what a tuple compare does.

Comment: @ysth yeah, I was trying to avoid building out the expanded one as I can have a variable number of properties.

Comment: another equivalent that may work better with a variable number of properties but requires you to know which are numeric (and I don't think works in postgres; not sure about querydsl) is `coalesce(nullif(field1 cmp value1,0), nullif(field2 cmp value2,0), nullif(field3 <=> value3,0)) < 0`